# Linking to non-home panel in JQTouch site

Tags: jquery, iphone, jqtouch

I'm trying to create a link from an external site that arrives at a particular, internal panel on a JQTouch site I'm building. However the browser always opens the home panel of the JQT site no matter what anchor tag I use in the link.

e.g. If I try to link to the User Interface panel in the official JQTouch demo I use http://www.jqtouch.com/preview/demos/main/#ui but the home panel shows in the browser and not the sub-panel I requested.

Any suggestions would be very welcome. I have control of the both the linked and linking sites so can tweak code is necessary.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

According to the source code (http://code.google.com/p/jqtouch/source/browse/trunk/jqtouch/jqtouch.js) - jqTouch will load whatever portion of your page first has the `current` class added to it.

Line 179 of jqtouch.js:

```
// Make sure exactly one child of body has "current" class
if ($('#jqt > .current').length == 0) {
  currentPage = $('#jqt > *:first');
} else {
  currentPage = $('#jqt > .current:first');
  $('#jqt > .current').removeClass('current');
}

// Go to the top of the "current" page
$(currentPage).addClass('current');
location.hash = '#' + $(currentPage).attr('id');
addPageToHistory(currentPage);
```

So the best thing to do might be to check your `window.location.hash` variable *before* you run the jqtouch source, and set which ever hash is there to the `current` class.

Something along the lines of this heuristic:

```
<script include jquery>
<script>
var cur = document.location.hash;
if (cur) {
  $('.current').removeClass('current');
  $(cur).addClass('current');
}
</script>
<script include jqtouch>
```